# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object or LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

I write named query like this

```
<query name="GET_QUESTIONS_BY_TEST_ID">select tq from TestQuestion as tq inner join tq.question as
        q
        where
        tq.testQuestionIdentifer.versionId=(select
        max(tq.testQuestionIdentifer.versionId) from TestQuestion tq_inner
        where
        tq_inner.testQuestionIdentifer.testId=:testId) and
        tq.testQuestionIdentifer.testId=:testId
    </query>
```

And when I get result I have a problem. When I write just `from TestQuestion` I get `List<Object[Object[]]>` with Question and TestQuestion objects. When I write  `select tq` I get `LazyInitializationException`. I want to get List but can't.

**UPDATED**

I decided add other part my hbm

```
<class name="by.bsuir.testapp.model.TestQuestion" table="TEST_QUESTION"
        lazy="true">
        <composite-id name="testQuestionIdentifer"
            class="by.bsuir.testapp.model.TestQuestionIdentifer">
            <key-property name="testId" column="TEST_ID" />
            <key-property name="versionId" column="VERSION_ID" />
            <key-property name="questionId" column="QUESTION_ID" />
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="question" class="by.bsuir.testapp.model.Question"
            fetch="join" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="QUESTION_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
```

I find that exist `11.4.1.2. Queries that return tuples` in documentation of Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing)

How I should write named query for rignt result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your problem.

Your query (`select tq from TestQuestion as tq...` and `from TestQuestion`) should both return `List<TestQuestion>` instead of `List<Object[][]>`

`LazyInitializationException` normally occur when there is lazy-fetching occurring, but the related session of the entity is closed already (please correct me if I am wrong, just from my bare memory I thought it is `LazyInitializationException`).  It has nothing to do with named query.  Please make sure your transaction control etc is setup correctly.

Comment: What can be the reason  that I get not List<TestQuestion> ?

Comment: In accoring with documentation this result means that query return tuples instead of List<TestQuestion>

Comment: You have TestQuestion mapped, you are selecting the entity, the select clause contains only one entity, you are writing HQL.... Then you should get List<TestQuestion> instead of tuples.  By what means you think you will get List<Object[][]> instead of List<TestQuestion> ?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood what you mean: You mean you actually get the tuples instead of List<TestQuestion> right? (I thought you think you should get the tuples but you are not)  Your query doesn't seems causing the problem, have you tried to query directly through session instead of using Named query?  Is the quoted named query being your actual query?